# WPF why doesn't the initial binding trigger setter?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

i have the following `Button`

```
<Button x:Class="MvvmAttempt.UpdownButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvvmAttempt"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <Button.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="resources/Styles.xaml"/>
    </Button.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock x:Name="numCopyTB" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=Text}"/>
            <!--<TextBlock x:Name="numCopyTB"/>-->   <-- doesn't work propery
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource updownBlock}"/>
        </Viewbox>

    </Grid>
</Button>
```

**its codebehind**

```
public partial class UpdownButton : Button 
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(UpdownButton));


    public UpdownButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return GetValue(TextProperty) as string; }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value);
              //numCopyTB.Text = Text; <-- doesn't work properly
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see, I've added a `Text` property to `UpdownButton`, which derives from `Button`. The `TextBlock` named `numCopyTB` has its `Text` property bound to that of `UpdownButton`, so the `Text` of `UpdownButton` shows up on the `TextBlock` and updates correctly too.

However, commenting out the binding in XAML, and setting `numCopyTB`'s `Text` in codebehind doesn't work quite right: no text is shown initially; only subsequent calling `myUpdownButton.Text="new text";` works. The initial `Text` property is bound like follows:

```
<local:UpdownButton Text="{Binding Path=Copies, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

So it seems that the original binding doesn't trigger `Setter` in code behind. Why not?

Comment: if the old xaml is just `<TextBlock x:Name="numCopyTB"/>`, of course it won't work. There is not any binding between the Button's Text and the inner `TextBlock`'s Text here.

Comment: shouldn't the initial binding to `UpdownButton`'s `Text` implicitly calls `myUpdownButton.Text="newString";`, which updates the `TextBlock`?

Comment: if the old xaml is what you commented above, I don't think it works even right after loaded you explicitly set `myUpdownButton.Text="newString"`, I think you should double check and re-confirm it. Of course the current XAML should work.

Comment: looks like I understand what you mean, if using all the commented code (both in xaml and in codebehind) instead, you of course can just set the `Text` in codebehind, XAML binding will bypass this `numCopyTB.Text = Text;` but setting the property in codebehind won't, so it works.

Comment: yes. so i am just wondering why XAML would bypass the setter... maybe not a constructive question, since i already have a working version?

Comment: that's simply by design, you may want to ask the XAML designers why so. This is also noticed in the msdn page about DependencyProperty, try reading this ***[XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563(v=vs.110).aspx)***. Finally we can just know that's how it's implemented, so follow it other than ask for why.